# My onLocationChange method is not being called

Tags: android, google-maps

I have downloaded an android map project. And now i want to do something like this and i have implemented all of this thing but i am getting that on Location Changed method is not being called in my project but in other this method is being called. I am saying this because dialog is not being dismissed, zooming, and icon is not working,
Is there is way to solve this? or can we do all of that thing in on Map Ready which i have done in on Location change.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 50;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        //Check if Google Play Services Available or not
        if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
            Log.d("onCreate", "Finishing test case since Google Play Services are not available");
            finish();
        } else {
            Log.d("onCreate", "Google Play Services available.");
        }

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        0).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }


/*
        Button btnRestaurant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRestaurant);
        btnRestaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String Restaurant = "restaurant";

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
                mMap.clear();
                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                Log.d("onClick", url);

 GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(SearchMasjid.this, "Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*//*

            }
        });

        Button btnHospital = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHospital);
        btnHospital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String Hospital = "hospital";

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
                mMap.clear();
                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Hospital);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                Log.d("onClick", url);
                GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(SearchMasjid.this, "Nearby Hospitals", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Button btnSchool = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSchool);
        btnSchool.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String School = "school";

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
                mMap.clear();
                if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                    mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
                }
                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, School);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                Log.d("onClick", url);
                GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(SearchMasjid.this, "Nearby Schools", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        });
    }

*/
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {

        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        //googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + "28.5930325" + "," + "77.05343359374999");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyBYPKKBsAmKVzKpsDWpPzQFM-FgUCOdRsc");
        Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
        return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());

        /*StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=qgYvCi0wMDAwMDAxNDczYmQyNDUxOjM5MGQxYWQ5MDFmOjAxNGY2ZWNiZjkyN2QzYWE&key=AIzaSyBYPKKBsAmKVzKpsDWpPzQFM-FgUCOdRsc");
        Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
        return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        HomeActivity.lats=String.valueOf(latitude);
        HomeActivity.lngs=String.valueOf(longitude);
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
       // Toast.makeText(SearchMasjid.this, "Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f", latitude, longitude));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                }
            });
            Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
        }
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");
        hidePDialog();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which project did you download? Is there an exception stacktrace? Can you give us the link and edit the question with more details and the code snippet that you are trying to run.

Comment: no, this project is working well, and my project is also... but the problem is that, onLocationChange() is not being called...

Comment: please see the question again, i have added the code snippet as well

Comment: Is there any way through which i can call on location change method with in on ready ,map?

Comment: i have the same problem, I'm using a Lollipop version device, which Android version are you using?

Comment: i am facing this problem on kitkat version

Answer (score 0):

this is the exact answer of my question.
In that case, you have to request location updates as described at developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/g‌​ms/…. You should do this in your onCreate() method. Your current location listener is from the incorrect package for your use. Use the location listener from the Google API package –

They should all be from the com.google.android.gms package. Make sure you are uniform when using the API

Answer (score -1):

In order to use the onLocationChanged(Location) callback, you need to register your location listener with the location manager. Something like:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Since you have implemented the locationListener interface, for you it will look something like:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Comment: Where have to put up this line? And what is the need of network or gps provider? I am using fused location.

Comment: First time i was using this network and gps location manager, but getLastKnownLocation method is not perfect to get exact location

Comment: and here is one and only problem is my onLocationChange method is not being called at first time when i am opening my application

Comment: In that case, you have to request location updates as described at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener. You should do this in your onCreate() method. Your current location listener is from the incorrect package for your use. Use the location listener from the Google API package

Comment: I will check it, but can you please tell which package of onLocationChange should be used?

Comment: They should all be from the com.google.android.gms package. Make sure you are uniform when using the API